# Replacement of text in any EditText view of any app

Tags: android

There are apps like Texpand which are able to replace text in any EditText view - even of views which are part of other apps. Looking at the app-info this is happening without any requested permissions. I'm scratching my head how this is done - my (rookie) understanding is that each app resides in its own separated sandbox, so it should not have direct access to other apps views?

I looked for possible global events which could be provided by any central manager, but found nothing. More likely I would expect the replacement to be done passively (that means without the app being aware of the actual EditText), but checking for possible bindings or user dictionaries I found nothing promising either.

Looking at my Android system it seems the app is neither using permissions nor installing a keyboard. Additionally I don't see any entries in my user dictionary. Does anybody have an idea how the described functionality could actually be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Texpand's Google Play posting indicates that it uses [Accessibility Services](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/services.html). Accessibility services are a set of APIs Android offers to help build tools to allow non-standard interactions with apps (such as audio descriptions/voice commands) to expand access to the platform to people with an impairment that might otherwise prevent them from using a touch-screen/smart-phone.

These include the ability to [take action](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/services.html#act-for-users) on the behalf of a user, such as filling in text fields.

Comment: Please note that Google has recently announced it would ban from the Play store apps which use accessibility apis for non-accessibility reasons.  If you want to release your app I'd be wary of using them.

Comment: @emerssso: Thank you! It's a bit embarassing to be honest to find the answer in the app's Google Play Description, but I will consider checking there as well in the future.

Comment: @GabeSechan Thanks for the hint. Seems Google backed down a bit on the ban: http://www.androidpolice.com/2017/12/07/google-pauses-accessibility-app-ban-considers-responsible-innovative-uses-accessibility-services/

Comment: @ChristianWegmann Right now its up in the air.  If you're writing for your own benefit, go for it.  If you're looking to monetize it, I might hesitate to throw a lot of resources into it until things are clarified.  But that's your call.